# Given an unsorted array, Find the maximum subtraction between two elements in the array

Tags: arrays, max, maximize

I've got this question from an Interview in Microsoft: Given an unsorted array, Find the maximum subtraction between two elements in the array is a way that:

```
(Index1, Index2) = arr[Index2] - arr[Index1].    Index1<Index2.
```

Example:

```
given the array: [1, 5, 3, 2, 7, 9, 4, 3] -> Output: (1,9)=8.
given the array: [4, 9, 2, 3, 6, 3, 8, 1] -> Output: (2,8)=6.
```

The naive solution works in O(n^2) times: Scan the first index for subtraction with all other indexes and save the max value, Continue to the next index and so on.

Is there any way to optimize this?

Comment: It doesn't have to be the (min,max), Check example two.

Comment: So, the other constraint is that 1 appears as element 1 and 2 as element 2?

Comment: Clarified the definition, Sorry.

Comment: Are you working with 0-based or 1-based indexing? What exactly do you mean by `(Index1, Index2) = Index2 - Index1`? I cannot make sense of your first example. Perhaps you should just post the interview question *verbatim*, for clarity.

Comment: @Jubobs The function to maximize is `(index1, index2) => arr[index2]- arr[index1]`. The constraint is that `index1 < index2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fairly simple when you write it down. Rephrasing the problem, you want to find the largest element to the right of each element. Now given the first example, this is:

```
[1, 5, 3, 2, 7, 9, 4, 3]
=>
[9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 4, 3]
```

Now, notice the maximums array is just the cumulative maximums from the right. Given this property it is easy to construct an `O(n)` time algorithm.

Implementation in python:

```
def find_max(xs):
    ys = []
    cur_max = float('-inf')
    for x in reversed(xs):
        cur_max = max(x, cur_max)
        ys.append(cur_max)
    ys = ys[::-1][1:]
    return max(y - x for x, y in zip(xs, ys))
```

We can also construct the maximums array lazily, doing so gives us `O(1)` memory, which is the best possible:

```
def find_max(xs):
    cur_max = float('-inf')
    cum_max = xs[-1]
    for i in range(len(xs) - 2, -1, -1):
        cur_max = max(cur_max, cum_max - xs[i])
        cum_max = max(cum_max, xs[i])
    return cur_max
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is correct and O(nlogn): Split in the middle and select from right the max, from left the min value. Also split the the other 2 quarters, if one of them gives bigger result continue on that branch recursively.

Second example:

```
4, 9, 2, 3| 6, 3, 8, 1 -> 2 and 8
4, 9| 2, 3, 6, 3, 8, 1 -> 4 and 8
4, 9, 2, 3, 6, 3| 8, 1 -> 2 and 8
```

So working on the right split:

```
4, 9, 2, 3, 6, 3, 8| 1 -> 2 and 1
```

Selecting the `2` and `8` option. It also works for the first example.